# How to access user's video or other media files stored in iphone?

Tags: ios

I do not mean the assets inside the Photo app.

I want to know if it is possible at all to access media files a user have in Music or Videos on an iphone.

If it is possible, which framework I should use?

Comment: ps. Just now I find one app in my iPad can access the video.app list. And my iPad is with ios 5.1.1.

Comment: @luyuan: you're probably right. There is a new media type symbol 'MPMediaTypeMovie' available in ios5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems impossible without break jail.

ps. Just now I find one app in my iPad can access the video.app list. And my iPad is with ios 5.1.1. Maybe it is possible now!